# Converting a Excel value to Date in Informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Need your thoughts

Trying to Load excel to table using Informatica process

Source have a date value  (ex: 5/29/2020) where it read as 4398 which is number value we get in excel when we convert the date to number.

so the file reads the date column as 4398.
is there way we can convert back the number back to date.

Your suggestion would help us!!

Answer (score 0):

You might be opening the file manually. When the excel file is converted into csv, its a converted format and when you try to open it manually in excel format, the date formats gets changed. Please do not open the file manually. In case if you want to open the file for some validations, open it using notepad or notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Is it really an excel output or its a csv? Because in informatica generating excel directly need special connection, formatting etc. If output is a normal text file, then follow below steps -

1. open MS excel. Go to 'Data' tab. Click on 'From text'. Select your file and click 'Import'
2. You will be asked on delimiter etc. Mark all columns as text.
3. Press ok. You should get correct data in the xl.